# Python while как получить результат выполнения функции на один шаг цикла?

Tags: python-3.x

Имеется цикл в теле которого должна вызываться функция, но жизнь этой функции должна быть в пределах шага цикла...
Итак код:

```
class Viking:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.damage = 10
        self.hp = 100

    def crit (self):
        self.damage *= 3

x = Viking()

while True:
    x.hp -= 10
    if x.hp < 30:
        x.crit()
```

Вот при таком раскладе x.damage на всегда будет равен 30, а как сделать так, что бы на следующий шаг цикла x.damage снова был равен 10 не смотря на то что x.hp -= 10 продолжит выполняться.

Comment: Не всегда, а только в самую первую итерацию. Во вторую будет 90, потом 270 и т.д. Какую задачу вообще решаем? Почему возникла такая проблема?

Comment: Есть базовый урон, есть итоговый. Базовый пусть будет 10, а итоговый 10 * 3. Если итоговый дамаг будет считаться из базового, то не будет этого увеличения урона на каждый крит: `self.base_damage = 10` `self.damage = self.base_damage * 3`. Еще, у персонажа могут быть состояния (ваш крит, например). Состояния могут быть включены (True) или нет (False), вы можете при `x.hp < 30` включить состояние `Крит`, и в методе урона, при наличии этого состояния увеличить урон. Если же состояние уже было включено, а `x.hp < 30`, то выключить его

Comment: Так вот мне и нужно что бы первая итерация damage = 30, вторая (и последующие) снова 10... Задача очень простая, есть два класса Викинг и Рыцарь, они бьются внутри бесконечного цикла до тех пор пока hp > 0. У каждого из них есть "скилы" (def crit например) которые они могут использовать но нужно чтобы использовали только один раз.

Comment: gil9red а как можно включать функции?? Ну точнее как правильно использовать True и False?

Comment: @Uncle_Ragnar, пишите `@` перед ником, а то уведомление не увидел :) заведите переменную с словарем, например: `self.state = {"Crit": False, ...}`, придумайте для нее ключ-состояния (например через `enum`'ы). Если нужно включить состояние, то `self.state["Crit"] = True`. Если нужно проверить что состояние включено, то `if self.state['Crit']:`

Comment: @gil9red в словаре {"Crit": False} - Crit - это будет функция которая def crit(self) или нет? Не понимаю (((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Накидал пример:

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class State(Enum):
    Crit = auto()
    Live = auto()

class Viking:
    def __init__(self):
        self._base_damage = 10
        self._hp = 100

        self._states = {
            State.Crit: False,
            State.Live: True,
            # ...
        }

    @property
    def hp(self):
        return self._hp

    @hp.setter
    def hp(self, val):
        self._hp = val

        if self._hp <= 0:
            self._states[State.Live] = False

        if self._hp < 30:
            # Если уже было состояние Крит, выключаем его.
            # Если не было, то включаем
            # OR: self._states[State.Crit] = not self._states[State.Crit]
            if self._states[State.Crit]:
                self._states[State.Crit] = False
            else:
                self._states[State.Crit] = True

        # Если жизней стало больше, то выключаем крит
        else:
            self._states[State.Crit] = False

    @property
    def is_live(self):
        return self._states[State.Live]

    @property
    def damage(self):
        damage = self._base_damage

        # Под воздействие крита увеличен урон
        if self._states[State.Crit]:
            damage *= 3

        return damage

    def __str__(self):
        return f'<Viking(hp="{self.hp}" damage={self.damage} states={self._states})>'


x = Viking()

while x.is_live:
    x.hp -= 10
    print(x)
```

Консоль:

```
<Viking(hp="90" damage=10 states={<State.Crit: 1>: False, <State.Live: 2>: True})>
...
<Viking(hp="30" damage=10 states={<State.Crit: 1>: False, <State.Live: 2>: True})>
<Viking(hp="20" damage=30 states={<State.Crit: 1>: True, <State.Live: 2>: True})>
<Viking(hp="10" damage=10 states={<State.Crit: 1>: False, <State.Live: 2>: True})>
<Viking(hp="0" damage=30 states={<State.Crit: 1>: True, <State.Live: 2>: False})>
```

Comment: Извиняюсь за задержку, отвлекся и забыл за все.. Да, это именно то, что было нужно, спасибо!!!